# Can I map class to int and use it as primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, orm

I want to use purpose-specific id types (e.g. PersonId for Person class). It requires me to map my custom class (`PersonId`) to an `int` **and use it as primary key**

```
public class PersonId
{
    int Id;
}

public class Person
{
    PersonId Id;
    // ...
}
```

Can I map this classes in EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a class as the primary key isn't possible. With Entity Framework primary keys must be a primitive type or a byte[].

If you want to do something like that for something else than primary key you could make the PersonId class a Complex type.

```
[ComplexType]
public class PersonId
{
    int Id;
}
```

or with the fluent API

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.ComplexType<PersonId>();
}
```

but you won't be able to use that Id as the primary key of your entity

Comment: Unfortunately using it as a primary key is a key requirement ;p

Comment: Then what you want to do cannot be done. Only primitive or byte[] can be use as primary key using entity framework.